# Using StAX to parse text and element from parent element

Tags: java, stax

**DL/DR;**

I'm using `StAX` to stream parse XML files to extract some data.

The issue that I'm having is that when I run into an `element` that contains both text and another `element`, when I try to extract the text using `xmlEventReader.getElementText()`, it throws an exception as that method is expecting that parent `element` to only contain text.

```
<div>Hello <i>World</i>!</div>
```

The fact that the `div` tag directly contains both text and an `i` tag, is causing the text extraction to fail.

I would like to be able to extract `Hello World!` from the above sample XML.

**Whole Story**

I'm writing a small Java app to export my recipes currently stored in Evernote and then import them into another application.

*I'm just getting sick of Evernote's constant barrage to sign-up for PRO.*

I'm using `StAX` to stream parse the XML files which contain my notes which each contain a single recipe.

I'm able to export all of my notes from Evernote and now I need to parse those notes to extract my recipe data. The ingredients and directions are stored in the body of the note as HTML markup within a `CDATA element`.

I'm basically parsing through all of the XML/HTML elements and once I get to a `li` tag, I set the state that I'm within a `list-item` and any text within that I just concatenate together thus removing any HTML markup that was put-in as formatting.

It's working really well, but I'm running into a small issue when there is an `element` that contains both `text` and another `element`.

When I get to that parent element and I call `xmlEventReader.getElementText()`, it throws an exception as that method is expecting that `element` to only contain text.

**Sample XML**

*I've made this sample very simple and only contains a few directions, removing the ingredients logic.*

```
<en-note>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div>Add all ingredients to a </div>
            <div>ziplock freezer bag</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>Freezer until needed (<i>maximum 2 months</i>).</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</en-note>
```

**Here is the code that parses the body of the note.**

*I've simplified this code to remove any logic pertaining to the ingredients as it's not relevant to the issue.*

*The above XML would be loaded into the `recipeContent` variable at the top of the code sample.*

*The code breaks on `listItemValueSb.append(xmlEventReader.getElementText().trim()).append(" ");` when it's parsing the 2nd direction due to the `i` tag.*

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class Test
{
    
    public static void main(final String[] args)
            throws XMLStreamException
    {
        final String recipeContent = """
<en-note>
    <div><i>hello</i></div>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div>Add all ingredients to a </div>
            <div>ziplock freezer bag</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>Freezer until needed (<i>maximum 2 months</i>).</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</en-note>
""";
        
        Test.parseRecipeContent(
                recipeContent,
                (final List<String> directions) -> {
                    for (int n=0; n<directions.size(); n++)
                    {
                        System.out.println((n + 1) + ") " + directions.get(n));
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    
    private static void parseRecipeContent(
            final String recipeContent,
            final RecipeContentHandler recipeContentHandler
    )
            throws XMLStreamException
    {
        final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = null;

        try(
                final StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(recipeContent);
        )
        {
            xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(stringReader);
            XMLEvent currentEvent;
            StartElement tmpStartElement;
            EndElement tmpEndElement;
            boolean withinLiTag = false;
            StringBuilder listItemValueSb = null;
            final List<String> directions = new ArrayList<>();
            
            while (xmlEventReader.hasNext())
            {
                currentEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                
                // If the current event is an END-EVENT, then potentially end this recipe.
                if (currentEvent.isEndElement())
                {
                    tmpEndElement = currentEvent.asEndElement();
                    
                    switch (tmpEndElement.getName().getLocalPart().toLowerCase())
                    {
                        case "en-note":
                            // Inform the calling code of the newly found recipe.
                            recipeContentHandler.handleRecipeContent(
                                    directions
                            );
                            
                            break;
                        case "li":
                            withinLiTag = false;
                            
                            if (
                                    (listItemValueSb != null)
                                        &&
                                    (listItemValueSb.length() > 0)
                            )
                            {
                                directions.add(listItemValueSb.toString().trim().replaceAll("  ", " "));
                            }
                            
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    
                    continue;
                }
                
                // If the current event is a START-EVENT, then extract the relevant data.
                if (!currentEvent.isStartElement())
                {
                    if (
                            withinLiTag
                                &&
                            currentEvent.isCharacters()
                    )
                    {
                        listItemValueSb.append(currentEvent.asCharacters().getData().trim()).append(" ");
                    }
                    
                    continue;
                }
                
                tmpStartElement = currentEvent.asStartElement();
                
                switch (tmpStartElement.getName().getLocalPart().toLowerCase())
                {
                    case "en-note":
                        withinLiTag = false;
                        directions.clear();
                        
                        break;
                    case "li":
                        withinLiTag = true;
                        listItemValueSb = new StringBuilder();
                        
                        break;
                    default:
//                      final XMLEvent nextXMLEvent = xmlEventReader.peek();
//                      
//                      if (
//                              (nextXMLEvent == null)
//                                  ||
//                              !nextXMLEvent.isCharacters()
//                      )
//                      {
//                          break;
//                      }
                        
                        if (withinLiTag)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                listItemValueSb.append(xmlEventReader.getElementText().trim()).append(" ");
                            }
                            catch (Throwable thrown)
                            {
                                thrown.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xmlEventReader != null)
            {
                xmlEventReader.close();
            }
        }
    }
    
    /* PRIVATE INTERFACES */
    private static interface RecipeContentHandler
    {
        
        /**
         * This method will handle the specified {@link List} of
         * directions found.
         * 
         * @param directions
         * The {@link List} of directions.
         */
        void handleRecipeContent(List<String> directions);
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement seems to be that all text inside `li` is important regardless of the formatting. The use of `xmlEventReader.peek()` event does not handle this case well.

Instead it would be easier if you grabbed all the content text under `li` at the branch where you currently skip each event and "continue", changing here:

```
// If the current event is a START-EVENT, then extract the relevant data.
if (!currentEvent.isStartElement())  {
    // ensures all character content inside <li> is recorded
    if (withinLiTag && currentEvent.isCharacters()) {
        listItemValueSb.append(currentEvent.asCharacters().getData().trim()).append(" ");

    }
    continue;
}
```

The above line collects the trimmed inner text of `li`, and makes the code which peeks the stream in the "default" case of the last switch unnecessary ), so just comment out:

```
switch (tmpStartElement.getName().getLocalPart().toLowerCase()) {
    ...
    default:
        // comment out the default handling:
        // final XMLEvent nextXMLEvent = xmlEventReader.peek();
        // ...
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you @DuncG, I tried what you suggested, but the text within the `div` tag, but before the `i` tag is still being skipped. I've updated the code in my question to be fully stand-alone.

Comment: @MattWeiler I don't think you've taken the whole change - everything from `default: ... nextXMLEvent` to the break needs commenting out.

Comment: you are 100% correct. It now works as expected, thank  you.